# CassandraTemplate Autowire

Tags: spring-data

I try to test out cassandra for my storage and maybe changing it from mongo. 
I can't manage to autowire CassandraTemplate into my service getting.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraTemplate] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

I have test creating the bean via xml and @Configuration, this application is an big monolithic application with dependency to several spring-data projects, I don't know if that is related to the problem

```
mvn dependency:tree | grep spring-data
[INFO] +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:1.4.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:1.6.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-mongodb:jar:1.3.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-cassandra:jar:1.4.4.RELEASE:compile
```

When I debug @Configuration creating I see that I ends up in the Bean creation method but still my Service can not autowire that bean

```
@Bean
public CassandraOperations cassandraTemplate() throws Exception {
    return new CassandraTemplate(session().getObject());
}

@Autowired
public CacheServiceScylla(CassandraTemplate cassandraTemplate) {
    this.cassandraTemplate = cassandraTemplate;
}
```

I do not have any problem to to this with another application that is build with spring-boot.